# Push VS. Press; what's the difference?

Tags: word-choice

I searched a bit, but they say press is a slight move, like in "press the button", whereas push is more aggresive, like in "push to open(for door)". But I don't think these are great examples. For example, there's two famous exercise named push-up, bench-press, and I don't know why they are named so. And there's a "pressed ham" which is very strongly pressed literally. Please help.

Comment: In general, push is short, press is continuous.

Comment: In the context of activating a mechanism (door, button, etc), the main difference between "push" and "press" is whether the mechanism "fights back" or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collins Dictionary in its B1 definition for *press* says

> VERB B1
> If you *press* something somewhere, you push it ***firmly against*** something else [emphasis added].

To do that, the effort generally needs to be sustained.  The same dictionary in its A2 definition for *push* says

> VERB A2
> When you *push* something, you use force to make it move away from you or away from its previous position.

No sustained effort is implied here.

Other than the general difference stated above, in certain situations, the sustained/momentary difference may be less clear, depending on the extent of the action.  We say *push* a cart (or bicycle), but that may involve a sustained effort.  Elsewhere,  there are some overlaps in their usage, and both actions may be just momentary, for example, in *press* (or *push*) a button.

As for the strength involved, pressing can involve large effort too, as in benchpress.  This exercise and the other one may have got their names as shown below:

[push-up](https://www.etymonline.com/word/push-up#etymonline_v_45826):

> push-up (n.)
> also pushup, type of physical exercise (originally done on parallel bars), 1893, from the verbal phrase (by 1660s); see push (v.) + up (adv.).

[bench press](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/bench-press_v?tl=true#:%7E:text=The%20earliest%20known%20use%20of,formed%20within%20English%2C%20by%20conversion.):

> The earliest known use of the *verb bench press* is in the 1950s.

> OED's earliest evidence for bench press is from 1953, in Tomorrow's Man (Chicago).

> It is also recorded as a *noun* from the 1850s.